# How to plot graph with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to plot graph with a certain condition without manipulating my data frame.

For example, I created a countplot with a data frame that has a bunch of x-values that are less than 100, and in the countplot, those less than 100 comes up as "no-bar", and it's taking up space. So I want to just get rid of those empty (count < 100).

I tried to create another data frame with only count values higher than 100, but I wanted to know if there is a simpler/cleaner way to plot a graph, rather than creating a whole data frame.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,50))
plt.ylim(100,500)
sns.countplot(data=df, x='brand')
```

From this code, I see many empty bars caused by counting values less than 100, as xlim is set to 100-500.

Comment: You could pivot the dataframe, filter out those `< 100` and plot with `matplotlib`.

Comment: You can select/manipulate/etc. to the dataframe directly within the `seaborn` plotting command: e.g., `sns.countplot(data=df.loc[...], ...)`

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the cleanest way is to handle all data manipulation prior to the visualization code. Manipulate data -> Visual data. It's clean. You're trying to do Visual data -> Manipulate data, which I think is less intuitive and will probably make the code less readable. Conventionally, people seem to do Manipulate data -> Visual data and there's a lot of value in sticking with widely popular conventions. So, I'd recommend grouping your data by brand, counting rows by each brand, and then filtering the dataframe from there. Then use a barplot instead of countplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plot_data = df.groupby('brand').size().reset_index(name='count').query('count>=100')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,50))
plt.ylim(100,500)
sns.barplot(data=plot_data, x='brand', y='count')
```

Comment: @L.F. I didn't want to add explanation. If my answer wasn't up to your standards, then post your own answer.